What can I do to make the fish not stick to the pot?
I use a multicooker to fry rainbow trout.
I use this multicooker.
The recipe is like the following:

Cut a fish into 4–5 pieces.
Take one teaspoon of turmeric powder and one teaspoon of salt, and mix them well
Rub the mix on fish pieces
Set the cooker to [Deep Fry, 170°C] setting
Add two tablespoons of sunflower oil
Heat the oil for five minutes
Add fish pieces
Cook each side and turn them time to time
Take them out after 40 minutes

The problem I am facing is that fish are sticking to the multicooker pot. When I try to turn the piches over, they break.
What can I do to make the fish not stick to the pot?

I don't have this multi-cooker, nor to I use one, but here is a thought...works in a traditional pan...  If you don't want to deep fry, as suggested in another answer, but are instead looking to shallow fry, you might try placing a piece of parchment paper at the bottom of the cooker, before adding the oil.

Deep fry really means deep fry.
You should use about two liters of oil, not two tablespoons. Preheat for a really long time, until the whole thermal mass has stabilized at 170 (or if you can set it to 175, even better, that's the standard temperature). Then throw the fish in, wait until cooked through (you'll get a feeling for the time needed after a few tries) and take them out.
Rubbing with a spice mix isn't recommended for deep frying, since some powder will fall off the fish, settle onto the bottom of the pot, and burn, giving an acrid taste to all future pieces of fish in that oil. Consider using either unspiced fish, or batter it first and mix the spices in the batter.

Deep frying is not recommended given the amount of oil required. To shallow fry with 2 tbps of oil in a regular pan, just roll the fish around in a coating of semolina/ bread crumbs just before adding the fish to the heated oil- this will ensure that that you are able to turn the fish around without it breaking or sticking to the pan.
